# How to create a new xcode project copy that doesn't affect the original?

Tags: swift, xcode, duplicates, copy, save

Im just learning swift. I have this small xcode project that I want to keep the same. I am trying to duplicate this project, so that I can make all the changes that I want on this new project without affecting the original project. Currently when I duplicate this xcode project, whenever I edit the new one, it also edits the old one. Thus, I want the two projects to have the same code, but be completely separate.